# How do you name an alkene using IUPAC rules if the longest carbon chain in this alkene does not include the double bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

For example, which is the right way to name this compound:

[image: Compound]

Is it 2-bromo-4-methylenehexane or 4-bromo-2-ethylpent-1-ene?

Does the larger number of carbon in a chain take priority, as in the former, or does the carbon-carbon double bond take priority, as in the latter?

Answer (score 16):

The IUPAC recommendations on this matter have been changed. In the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*, the order of seniority between unsaturation and length of chain given in earlier recommendations is reversed:

> (…), the first criterion to be considered in choosing a preferred parent acyclic chain is the length of the chain; unsaturation is now the second criterion.

For example, a preferred IUPAC name is 3-methylidenehexane (not 2-ethylpent-1-ene) since the longer chain now supersedes a shorter unsaturated chain. (This example is given in the *Blue Book*.)

[image: 3-methylidenehexane]

Besides, the prefix ‘methylene’ is *no longer recommended* in IUPAC nomenclature to designate the $\ce{=CH2}$ group. The preferred prefix is ‘methylidene’.

Therefore, the correct name for your example is **2-bromo-4-methylidenehexane.**

[image: 2-bromo-4-methylidenehexane]

Comment: We are still taught in the eleventh and twelfth grade to give priority to the double bond, smh! Makes it all confusing.

Answer (score -2):

From wikipedia:

> Identification of the parent hydrocarbon chain. This chain must obey the following rules, in order of precedence:
>
> 1. It should have the maximum number of substituents of the suffix functional group. By suffix, it is meant that the parent functional group should have a suffix, unlike halogen substituents. If more than one functional group is present, the one with highest precedence should be used.

So the alkene takes priority over the alkane and **4-bromo-2-ethylpent-1-ene** is the correct name.

Comment: Gotta hate it when the gatekeepers change the rules right out from underneath one.