# Something is wrong with converting structure to name in ChemDraw 18.0

Tags: nomenclature

I am using the tool "convert structure to name" to name 2 organic compounds below. But, it seems the names are not wright. Can someone explain to me whether I am wrong or the software made a mistake?
[image]

Comment: ChemDraw's generated names are good enough for most organic chemists, but are not usually in accordance with latest IUPAC guidance. But that is not a chemistry issue. It is a software issue, which cannot really be thoroughly answered here, because we do not have insight into the algorithm they use. You may have better luck finding more info on their forums: http://forums.cambridgesoft.com/

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think they are wrong?

Comment: I think they are wrong because when choosing the parent of an alkene, we chose the longest chain that includes the pi bond so that the parents of these should be octadiene and heptene, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The names given by ChemOffice are not wrong since they describe the correct structures and are in accordance with IUPAC nomenclature rules. Note that a compound may be named correctly in two or more ways in accordance with the several methods recommended by IUPAC. Also note that the IUPAC recommendations have changed several times and the current (2013) recommendations are not included in ChemOffice yet.

The current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* includes the definition of a preferred IUPAC name (PIN), which is the name preferred among two or more names generated from two or more IUPAC recommendations including also the many retained names.

In particular, the name vinyl for $\ce{CH2=CH-{}}$ is retained for general nomenclature only. The systematic name **ethenyl** is the preferred IUPAC name.

Also in preferred IUPAC names, stereodescriptors are preceded by a numerical or letter locant to describe the position of the stereogenic unit when such locants are present.

Therefore, the preferred IUPAC names for the compounds that are given in the question are **(2﻿*Z*)-6-ethenyl-3,4-dimethylnon-2-ene** and **4-ethenyloctane,** respectively.

Comment: I am sorry because I did not make clear why I found they are wrong. Actually, I want to mention about the parent. I think we have to choose the longest chain that includes the pi bond so that the parents of these should be octadiene and heptene, respectively.

Comment: @HungNguyen No, see [How do you name an alkene using IUPAC rules if the longest carbon chain in this alkene does not include the double bond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28554/7951)

Comment: I got it, thank you very much. However, I wonder why some popular books, like David Klein's Organic Chemistry (2017), still use the previous rules?

Answer (score -2):

[image]

(2E)-6-ethenyl-3,4-dimethylnon-2-ene

using ACD chem

[image]

Comment: can I know where is Structure to Name option on ChemDraw I have chemDraw 19.0 , but I can't find that option,