# 3-propyl-penta-1,3-diene vs 3-ethylidene-hex-1-ene

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

From the rules I know I would name the following compound as **3-propyl-penta-1,3-diene** because maximum number of functional groups (double bonds in this case) are in the five numbered carbon chain:

[image]

However, ChemDraw names the above compound as **3-ethylidene-hex-1-ene**. Why? Am I missing a rule?

Comment: This compound also has stereochemistry ($E/Z$).

Comment: If we ignore E/Z nomenclature at the moment @Mathew Mahindaratne , what about the main name?

Comment: Naming rules include identifying the longest carbon chain.

Comment: I know that, but there is another rule that if there are functional groups present, we choose the longest chain which has maximum number of functional groups, and since it contains two double bonds IMO 5 numbered chain should be considered as parent chain. Can I get a reference? @z1273

Comment: Related: [How do you name an alkene using IUPAC rules if the longest carbon chain in this alkene does not include the double bond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28554/101286)

Comment: @Loong Can you provide a source from where I can refer nomencluature rules, I don't have access to the blue book.

Comment: @LightYagami Start here: [Brief guide to the nomenclature of organic chemistry (IUPAC Technical Report) 2020](https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2019-0104)