# Which is the correct parent chain in this compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

In this compound:[image]
Will the parent chain be the one inside the loop, or the longer one including the single bonds to the left of the vinyl group?

I know that carboxylic acid is the highest-priority functional group, and that it must therefore be included in the parent chain. However, once we have selected a highest-priority group, don't the rest of the functional groups (in this case, a double bond) take on substituent priority? Therefore, I believe that the longer chain will be the parent chain in this case.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Related: [How do you name an alkene using IUPAC rules if the longest carbon chain in this alkene does not include the double bond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28554/101286)

Comment: The illustration *looks like* being cropped from an illustration.  So, it is not clear if all of the structure currently is shown (then a hexanoic acid).

Comment: @Loong in that question, they talk exactly about unsaturation. Is it the same for carboxylic acid group though?

Comment: @Buttonwood I've cropped it shoddily but the entire molecule is shown. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite right about the feeling that the longer chain must be the parent chain,

According to the newly revised (IUPAC Blue Book 2013), the longest chain containing the functional group regardless of presence unsaturation (here the double bond) will be the parent chain

Check this answer for details regarding this [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/28558/114742)

Hence the parent chain will be a 6-Carbon chain with the carbonic acid functional group. Therefore the correct Preferred IUPAC Name (PIN) will be 4‐methyl‐3‐methylidenehexanoic acid